# Using regex to find an attribute with no letters in FME Workbench

Tags: fme-form, address, regular-expression

I need to divide address elements to lines. I am using 'TestFilter' transformator in FME Workbench to separate attributes with no letters. For this purpose I am using `IF` statement and regular expressions.

This is how Test Clauses look like:

```
Left Value        Operator           Right Value
HOUSE_NAME        Matches Regex      @FindRegEx(@Value(HOUSE_NUMBER),^[^A-Z]+$)
```

I am not sure if the syntax is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by putting **only** `^[^A-Z]+$` to the right value.